# Referenced table is unexceptionally droppable

Tags: mysql

When I use this query:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
   username varchar(30) not null unique,
   email varchar(255) not null unique,
   password varchar(255) not null
);

CREATE TABLE items(
   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
   name varchar(30) not null,
   user_id int not null,
   FOREIGN KEY user_key(user_id)
   REFERENCES users(id)
);
DROP TABLE users;
```

It shows this error:

> 1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Which is alright because that is how mySQL database naturally reacts when we want to drop table that is referenced by other table that depends on it.

However, this same query shows no errors and actually drops `users` table on my pal's PC.

What could be the case? Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Seems like one of your PAL's create table queries is failing on his PC. Check the error message and always have a drop table query before creating a table so that any unused object drops.

Comment: @fancyPants There is no data, tables are empty

Comment: Maybe `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` was set on that PC. Try  `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`

Comment: @juergend I just set it up to 0 and tried to drop table, 1217 still appars, so I don't think that would make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using different database engines. MyISAM and InnoDB have different FK support/enforcement, I believe. It could also be that the data in each of your tables is different.

If you want to drop a table that is a dependency of another table, though, the "right" way is to remove the FK from the dependent table and then drop the table that you want to.

Comment: both are innoDB (difference in versions is minor)